# Fetched Matched Array data in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have an MongoDB object like:

```
{
  "user" : ObjectId("60e5f88159292f575c0ca17f"),
  "questions" :[
     {
       question 'aaaaaaa',
       id :'1'
     },
     {  
       question 'bbbbbbb',
       id :'2'
     },
     {
       question 'ccccccc',
       id :'3'
     }
   ]
}
```

I want to pass an array of questions id ['1', '3'] and user object id. I want to fetch the question which matches the questions id and user.

My expected output should look like this:

```
{
  "user" : ObjectId("60e5f88159292f575c0ca17f"),
  "questions" :[
     {
       question 'aaaaaaa',
       id :'1'
     },
     {
       question 'ccccccc',
       id :'3'
     }
   ]
}
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way to achieve this using `aggregate`.

```
[
  {
    "$unwind": "$questions"
  },
  // filter out questions
  {
    $match: {
      "questions.id": {
        $in: [
          "1",
          "3"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  // regroup to original structure
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      questions: {
        $push: "$questions"
      },
      user: {
        $first: "$user"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

https://mongoplayground.net/p/LQmC6VG4s_S